# Do I need to repurchase Minecraft Java Edition? Post-"Post-migration process"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I purchased Minecraft years ago, from Mojang, and played it for many years.  However, I haven't played it in probably 4 or 5 years.  I think MS had purchased the game last I player, but you still loggged in with a Mojang account.  Today I decided to give it a look again, but I only have the option to log in with a Microsoft Account (I have one, and an XBox game pass), but it doesn't have my Minecraft Java Edition license.

I have found the [Minecraft: Java Edition Login Issues FAQ](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4409155824269-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Login-Issues-FAQ) on minecraft.net, but it is not entirely clear to me.  It only says:

> As of December 18, 2023, the post-migration process for Mojang accounts to Microsoft accounts for access to Minecraft has officially ended. If you successfully completed the post-migration process, you should now have access to both Java and Bedrock editions with your Microsoft account.
>
> As the migration period has concluded, Minecraft Support will no longer assist with account-related questions. Please visit these pages for help with your Microsoft account:

The "these pages" links are generic Microsoft Account help links, and are of no use.  The conclusion, "Minecraft Support will no longer assist with account-related questions", is unclear.  Are they saying that I've missed the window (that I never knew about) and must now purchase it again, or are they only saying that they no longer provide migration support, but migration is still possible?

Since I apparently missed the whole thing, I don't really understand the "post-migration process."  Can anyone confirm if I have in fact missed a window, or else point me in the right direction?

Comment: For more information and background about this migration, see [this Mojang blog post](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/java-edition-moving-house) (from 2020, so some of the links are broken).

Comment: @Kevin thanks for link!  Good info.  I have no problem with the move, but I am irritated that they put a deadline on it.  The post you linked claims "everyone will get an email", but I checked - 1 email from Mojang (my receipt for my original purchase), and 0 emails from Microsoft regarding Minecraft.

Answer (score 5):

Some additional clicking around Minecraft.net turned up [the answers I was looking for](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/19633473939981), that Google couldn't find.

Specifically,

> You no longer have access to your Java Edition account or Minecraft: Java Edition. To continue playing Minecraft, you will have to [buy Minecraft: Java & Bedrock Edition](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/6657208607501) using a Microsoft account.

- ["I Missed My Chance To Migrate. What Happens To My Account?" — Minecraft Help Center](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/19633473939981)

Comment: You could always just try contacting Mojang Support; if you have your original transaction ID, they should be able to find you, **especially if you still want to retain your old username**.

Comment: If they actually wanted to force you to buy it again, I wonder if it would hold up in court. Surely the license says something about no time limits.

Comment: I made sure to transfer my account just to keep my three letter username (not qwr)

Comment: @aytimothy: Apparently if you try, they just [send back a form response](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUFDRAEducI) telling you to buy the game again.